# why can I not access instance variables set w/ properties in super class?

Tags: objective-c

I've got the following object:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (readonly, strong) NSString *someVar;
@end

@implemtation Foo
@sythensize someVar = _someVar;
@end
```

And then I subclass it:

```
@interface Bar : Foo
-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)string;
@end

@implementation Bar
-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
  _someVar = string;
}
@end
```

but I get a "use of undeclared identifier _someVar".....  Why doesn't Bar know about foo's instance variable _someVar ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synthesized property of a protocol not seeing superclass' ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963417/synthesized-property-of-a-protocol-not-seeing-superclass-ivar), [Subclass of class with synthesized property cannot access ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943042/)

Comment: closely related: [What is the visibility of sythesized ivars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510464/), [Direct access to synthesized ivars in subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234063/)

Answer (score 1):

Always use getters/setters. Low level/direct access is only appropriate when seeking billionth of a second performance improvements, and in that case I question whether you should ditch Obj-C altogether and switch to just C.

Here is how I do it:

```
@synthesize someVar;

-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
  self.someVar = string;
}
```

Or, if I have a good reason not to use accessor methods, the. I don't use @synthesize at all.

Also, in the latest version of Xcode you can skip the `@synthesize` line.

Comment: It's not "not safe", it's _not possible_. The compiler won't let you do it. That's the point of the question.

Comment: By "not safe" I meant you shouldn't use that practice in any common code situation, even ones where it will work. I've updated my answer to explain it clearer.

Comment: I see..  My pattern has usually been to have readonly properties that I know aren't going to ever change, and just directly set their instance variable upon initialization of the instance, that way I wouldn't ever have to worry about some other object changing the value of one of these properties.....

Comment: Then declare it readonly in your public `@interface` and have a second  private `@interface` declaring it as read/write. Normally the second interface is "nameless" and in the same file as the `@implementation`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4586556/19851 Not sure about writing to these from a subclass, maybe update your question to ask that?